# How to log from Azure API Mangement Self Hosted Gateway without terminal control characters?

Tags: azure, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, azure-api-management

I'am using the Self Hosted Gateway option of Azure API Management and running the containers in AWS ECS where we capture the stdout to Cloudwatch.

We have set the `telemetry.logs.std=json` but the output is captured like this in AWS Cloudwatch:

```
[37m{"level":"Informational","timestamp":"...."}[0m
```

The control characters at the start and end of each line make it impossible to parse the JSON output with e.g. Metric Filters.

How can we prevent the container from printing these control characters to stdout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an [undocumented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/how-to-configure-local-metrics-logs#logs) feature to disable color output from the Azure API Management Self Hosted Gateway container. Add this env-var to your container:

`telemetry.logs.std.color=false`

I figured it out through a [helm chart](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-self-hosted-gateway/tree/main/helm-charts/azure-api-management-gateway) that I found that supports disabling color output. It's documented in the readme there, but that isn't the exact env-var name yet. I looked at the [commit that added support to the helm chart](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-self-hosted-gateway/commit/6550be4681b2d438a737569c99c681606ae80193#diff-55215e612bc4f72efee31d5dbe80e14858f1bf8ab0ecc16063cb235afe6b8d85R13) to figure out the env-var I needed to use. It seems to be a recent addition, so maybe that's why it isn't in the official documentation yet. I only works on recent versions of the SHG image (I needed to update our container for it to work).